# Invalid conversion from char to char compiler error

Tags: c++

```
void Emplyee::setname (char Name[50])
{ name [50] = Name [50] ;      }

void Emplyee::setadress (char Adress [100])
{  adress [100] = Adress [100] ;      }

Number.setname (Name [50]);   \\ Error in this Line

Number.setadress (Adress [100]);  \\ Error in this Line
```

Comment: Why `char` arrays instead of `std::string`? In any case, you seem to have misunderstood the concept of array subscripts.

Comment: you should add description with your code.

Comment: [**Read this please**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @WhozCraig Simply use `ask` in square brackets, like this: [ask].

Comment: @cybermonkey You're my hero man. Been doing it the hard way to two *years* now. Maybe  ***I*** should go spend some time on the help docs =P

Comment: You should really be adding a description with your code, as well as this your code has multiple errors. For example comments are `//` not `\\`.

Comment: @WhozCraig We're in the same boat, today I discovered how to format links in comments!

Answer (score 2):

You've declared your function arguments to be of type `char[]` but you're calling the function with an *element* of a char array, which is of type `char`. Call the function with just `Name` and `Adress`

You've got other issues with your code around the usage of arrays, but this will fix the compiler error in question. It won't fix the other issues you're going to see...

I'll point some of them out...

```
void Emplyee::setname (char Name[50])
{ 
    name [50] = Name [50] ;   // this line won't do what you think it does. (look at strcpy...)
       //  ^           ^
       //  |-----------|------ also, subscript out of bounds...
}
```

Also, same with address.

```
char name[50]; // declares an array of chars, called name, with a size of 50 elements
// ...
char c = name[50]; // access the 50th element (out of bounds, btw) of the name array, and assign to c. has nothing to do with size.
```

Comment: Though I highly suspect you're correct in the array subscript being out of bounds for `name[]`, there is no definitive proof it is not large enough to accept a subscript of `50`. You're *very* likely correct for `Name[]`, however, but even there as a parameter that number becomes meaningless, as `Name` is converted to a `char*` regardless.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, understood. I made a guess based on the usage that the OP is mistaking the use of the subscript for the full size, and decided to point out that it's easier to think of it as a subscript out of bounds, rather than a valid subscript that might result in undefined behavior if the buffer length is exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

```
name [50] = Name [50] ;
```

This doesn't do what you think it does, it overwrites element 51 of name with element 51 of Name. It doesn't copies the whole arrays, just one element. That's also probably a buffer overflow error.

This whole code shows that you don't understand arrays, I think you'd have less trouble with std::string for now.
Here's a simple example based on what you wrote :

```
#include <string>

class Emplyee{
    std::string address, name;

public:
    void setname (std::string Name)
    { name = Name ;      }

    void setadress (std::string Adress)
    {  adress = Adress ;      }
};

Emplyee Number;

Number.setname ("AAAA");

std::string Address = "Your address here";
Number.setadress (Address);
```

Finally I'd like to say that comments are // not \\ and that it's good to try and respect the language's naming conventions when possible for consistency.